# Unable to add Jedis module to Play 2.4.1 even though following the exact instructions

Tags: playframework, jedis

I'm following the instructions on https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/redis#how-to-install.

When I compile, it says that the plugin doesn't exist... What am I doing wrong...

My build.sbt after adding the plugin:

```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-modules-redis" % "2.4.1"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redis `README.md` instruction is pointing to the wrong group ID. You'll need this instead:

```
"com.typesafe.play.modules" %% "play-modules-redis" % "2.4.0"
```

and you'll probably need to add this resolver too:

```
resolvers += "google-sedis-fix" at "http://pk11-scratch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk"
```

I've just tried this with vanilla Play 2.4 and the dependency is now resolved.

Comment: very cool. could you let me know where you found the solution?

Comment: ah nvm, it was on the github page. looks like it just updated last night.

Comment: That was updated by me this morning :) See this pull request: https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/pull/150

Comment: I just had a look at the Maven repository and saw that the modules had a different group ID for 2.4, corrected the README.md and submitted the pull request.